# How to send text value to my controller using asp.net Mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i'm new in asp MVC so I will try to make a login form with ajax so i write jsonresult to check the username and password in the controller and i call it in ajax but it's not working when i write the right username and password show in log message login filed that's my controller code

```
public ActionResult login()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]

public JsonResult ValidateUser(string username,string password)
{
    using(var contxt=new EnglisCenterEntities())
    {
        var data = from a in contxt.Employee
                   where a.Username == username && a.Passwords == password
                   select a;
        if(data.Count()>0)
        {
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my view and ajax code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 alert alert-warning">
    <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group" id="log">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning form-control" type="submit" id="savedata"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;Login</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
          <script>
               $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('#log').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                       var data = {
                               username: function () { return $("#username").val(); },
                               password: function () { return $("#password").val(); }
                           };
                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/Account/ValidateUser",
                           type: "Post",
                           data:data,
                           dataType: "json",

                           success: function (response) {
                               if (response.Success) {
                                   $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")", function (data) {
                                       $('.container').html(data);
                                   });

                               }
                               else
                                   window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";
                           },
                           error: function () {
                               console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                           }
                       });
                   });
               });
     </script>
```

So why the ajax code not do check in the username and password?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? (and change the button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`)

Comment: Based on your last edit you need to remove `contentType: "application/json",` if your not stringifying the data

Comment: i getting Login Fail!!!

Comment: Have you removed `contentType: "application/json",`? And what are the details - use you browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response.

Comment: I removed  contentType: "application/json" and used firfox debuging doesn't make any thing and doesn't appear any errors

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code!

Comment: FYI: from security prospective, you should add antiforgery token at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 errors in your code:

```
var data = {
    username: function() { return $("#username").val(); },
    password: function() { return $("#password").val(); }
};
```

This will help you do get actual values of your inputs.

And don't stringlify your object just pass it:

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    data: data,
    //...    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
  event.preventDefault(); on your submit button click 

$('#some-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();   

//Rest of your code here  
}
```

Comment: According to edit the mistakes did not appear error , but still not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a model value to controller means you can assign value into a variable and post that variable. But here, you get two parameter value in controller. So, you pass two parameter like this and also change the button type into button:

```
 <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#savedata').click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: "/Account/ValidateUser",
                       type: "Post",
                       data:{"username": $("#username").val(),
                       "password": $("#password").val()
                   };,
                       dataType: "json",
                       contentType: "application/json",
                       success: function (response) {
                           if (response.Success) {
                               $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")", function (data) {
                                   $('.container').html(data);
                               });

                           }
                           else
                               window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";
                       },
                       error: function () {
                           console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                       }
                   });
               });
           });
 </script>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as OP is currently doing!

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you for your answers and your Bring your help it's working this is my code

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

               $('#savedata').click(function (e) {
                           e.preventDefault();
                           var data = {
                               username: function () { return $("#username").val(); },
                               password: function () { return $("#password").val(); }
                           };
                           $.ajax({
                               url: "/Account/validateuser",
                               type: "POST",
                               data: data,
                               dataType: "json",

                               success: function (response) {
                                   if (response.Success) {
                                       $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")", function (data) {
                                           $('.container').html(data);
                                       });

                                   }
                                   else
                                       window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";
                               },
                               error: function () {
                                   console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                               }
                           });
                       });
                   });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with it - its no different from your previous code. That twice now you have accepted a wrong answer.

Comment: var data = {
                               username: function () { return $("#username").val(); },
                               password: function () { return $("#password").val(); }
                           }; when i edit my code to this part it's worked

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for your help I really appreciate  :)

Comment: That makes not the slightest difference - `username: function () { return $("#username").val();` is the same as `username: $("#username").val();` which is what you had before!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change JQuery ajax to [JQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.get('/Account/ValidateUser', { username: "xyx", password: "xyz"})
                    .success(function (response) {
                       if (response.Success) {
                               $.get("@Url.Action("Index", "Home")", function (data) {
                                   $('.container').html(data);
                               });
                           }
                           else
                               window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Login", "Account")";
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                      console.log('Login Fail!!!');
                    });
```